# Cant see document libraries in content by query webpart

Tags: development

I have the following Content query webpart created by code. But its not showing me the last modified documents as I need, when I go to edit page and check the webparts properties, it does not even allow me to select document libraries.

[image]

```
  #region Last updated documents
                            ContentByQueryWebPart cqwp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
                        cqwp.BaseType = "1";
                            cqwp.ContentTypeBeginsWithId = Constants.ContentTypes.Base.xxxDocument.ID;
                            cqwp.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                            cqwp.Title = "Recent Documents";
                            string query = @"<Where>" +
                                                "<BeginsWith>" +
                                                    "<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/>" +
                                                        "<Value Type='Text'>" + Constants.ContentTypes.Base.PwcDocument.ID + "</Value>" +
                                                "</BeginsWith>" +
                                            "</Where>" +
                                            "<OrderBy> " +
                                                "<FieldRef Name='Modified'  Ascending='FALSE'/> " +
                                            "</OrderBy>";
                            cqwp.QueryOverride = query;
                            cqwp.ItemLimit = 10;
                            //cqwp.ListsOverride = "<Lists ServerTemplate='101'/>";
                            cqwp.WebsOverride = "<Webs Recursive='False' />";

                            cqwp.MainXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl");
                            cqwp.HeaderXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl");
                            cqwp.ItemXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/xxxdmsitem.xsl");

                            cqwp.CommonViewFields = "Name,Text;ContentType,Text;Modified,DateTime;Editor,User";  

                            mgrPageManager.AddWebPart(cqwp, "Footer", 0);
                            mgrPageManager.SaveChanges(cqwp);
                        #endregion
```

Comment: Are you sure that your site contains document libraries?

Comment: of course yes.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick here is the basetype and listsoverride, apparently both cant be set at the same time on code, when I removed the basetype line then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The items in this drop down are taken from the property [ListTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.listtemplates.aspx) of your web, The web is chosen according to what you have chosen in the "Source" section:

- If you have chosen a web (second option) - you get the `ListTemplates`
  of this web.
- If you have chosen a list (third option) - you get the
  `ListTemplates` of the parent web of this list.
- Otherwise - you get the
  `ListTemplates`  of your current web.

So you need to check the property `ListTemplates` of your web - what it contains?